# Why am I getting 404 not found in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to send a string to a client by this abstract class:

```java
public abstract class Command{
    protected String description;

    public Command(String description) {
        this.description=description;
    }

    public abstract void execute(String text);

    public abstract String writeToClient( String text);
}
```

and class that extends this abstract class:

```java
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/")
public class uploadCommand extends Command{

    public uploadCommand() {
        super("1. upload a time series csv file\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(String text) {
        text= writeToClient("Please upload your local train CSV file.\n");
    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping(path = "/ret/text", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    @Override
    public String writeToClient(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "text") String text) {
        return text;
    }
```

When I use Postman to send a `GET` request to:

```
http://localhost:6033/api/ret/text
```

I get the following response:

```json
{"timestamp":"2021-02-22T14:16:40.526+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"","path":"/api/ret/text"}
```

If I run it from the client I get this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:6033/api/ret/text' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.


xhr.js:178 GET http://localhost:6033/api/ret/text net::ERR_FAILED


Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:83)
```

Comment: What is the url you're calling? Also do you somewhere set a servlet-context? i.e. if your application should listen on the root `/` or on some subpath `/myApp`

Comment: Per Lino's comment, it seems likely that you have a servlet-context path set - there are various ways this can be done, as described [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-context-path)

Comment: The second error you have (where you run it from a client) is different, and is about CORS. Read up on that, or ask a separate question, but first I'd suggest solving the 404 problem from Postman.